# Shifting csv time series to have similar starting position and removing data points if necessary

Tags: python, time-series, shift

I'm struggling to figure out a way to "shift" the data from .csv's, in order to bring all of the .csv's to an even starting position?

Is there a straightforward method in Python to do this?

In my photo below, the data series which are shifted, are in the black rectangle, and I want to bring them to the left.  It would be OK to throw out the first points also (where y=20); as these data points are not important to me.

```
# We will first set a variable for the filenames that start with K, and another variable for the filenames
# that start with a Z.  The glob function allows us to reach through the directory searching only for these files.
filenamesK = glob("C:/Users/Kl*.csv")


# We will create a function for plotting, instead of nesting lots of if statements within a long for-loop.
def plot_data(filename, fig_ax, color):
    
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',',skiprows=24) # Read in the csv.
    df.columns=['sample','Time','ms','Temp1'] # Set the column names
    df=df.astype(str) # Set the data type as a string.

    df["Temp1"] = df["Outlet"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float) # Convert to float
                           
    fig_ax.plot(df[["Temp1"]], color=color)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))


for f in filenamesK:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'red')

#for f in filenamesZ:
 #   plot_data(f, ax, 'blue')
      

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: should'nt `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))` be tabulated to fit in the def ? For the tests, could you produce at least 2 csv samples ?

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work with the plt.subplots outside.  Second, what's the best method to attach a csv?

Comment: quote from the home policy  : `Sample data should be of sufficiently small size to avoid requiring attachments to communicate.`, maybe just give few lines from two different series, just to try this time-shift. Even with very few datas, we should see things

Answer (score 0):

You can read your variables with index

df["Temp1"][50:100]
df["Outlet"][50:100]

Remember, all variables you wnat to plot needs has the same dimension.

Bye.